# Checking if road passes through a trapezoid?

Tags: coordinates, road

I have a straight road defined by 2 points with latitude and longitude.
I also have a trapezoid defined by 4 points with latitude and longitude.
How do I check if the road passes through that trapezoid?

Comment: Which software are you using? or would you use PostGIS?

Comment: I am using c++ 17 with Osmium.

Comment: If you're using Osmium, you should have gdal installed. Could you use the 'intersect' method? http://www.gdal.org/classOGRGeometry.html#aadb34b556c52aef3e93f03cf65d3f4bc

Comment: That looks like an amazing solution. How can I do it if I initially have 4 osmium::Node at the corners of trapezoid and osmium::Way as the road?